# Setting out SQL Server Report Services not in Gridview form

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I am trying to create a SQL Server Reporting Services report to display all the records in a table.

However I don't want it to be in gridview form as one of the fields is very long.

The only way I seem to make all the records display (and not just the last record) is to use a Table.

So this way all my fields are listed just like an excel table.

Is it possible to display it more like a C# Repeater?

The format would be something like this:

```
 Name  -   Truck Number   -  Trailer Number 
 Notes
```

---

```
 Name  -   Truck Number   -  Trailer Number 
 Notes
```

As opposed to

```
 Name - Truck Number - Trailer Number - Notes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the detail row handle on the far left (a grey box with three horizontal lines) and insert a row below. Put your Notes field in that inserted row.

You may want to merge some cells to have it take up the entire row. Highlight the cells you want to merge and use `Merge Cells` from the right-click menu or the main toolbar.

You may want to hide the Notes row if there are no notes for that entry. Click the row handle to select the row (if SSRS 2005) or right-click it and choose `Row Group`->`Group Properties` and go to the `Visibility` section (if SSRS 2008) and set the `Visibility`-`Hidden` property to something like:

```
=Fields!Notes.Value = Nothing
```